# Updating Database Directly and Bypassing Hibernate - Does hibernate have a "Check and Clean All" feature?

Tags: hibernate

People are executing update/insert/delete sql directly against the database, as opposed to using the APIs, thus bypassing Hibernate (don't ask, it just is). As such, the audit tables are not getting updated.

Does hibernate contain some kind of "Check and Clean All" feature that will update the audit tables or do we need to role our own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such feature in Hibernate.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Couldn't find any project on github either.